# Rollback form one database to other database in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, oracle10g

I'm have two database **DB1** and **DB2**, using the following stored procedure to archive datas form one database to another database

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "DB1"."ARCHIVE"(FROM_ARCHIVE timestamp, TO_ARCHIVE timestamp)
AS
    v_err_num NUMBER;
    v_err_msg VARCHAR2(200);

    CURSOR MY_CURSOR IS
        SELECT
               ID,A,B,C
        FROM
            TABLE1 WHERE A >= FROM_ARCHIVE AND A <= TO_ARCHIVE

BEGIN
    FOR MY_LOOP IN MY_CURSOR
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            INSERT
            INTO
                DB2.TABLE2
                (
                A,B,C
                )
                VALUES
                (
                MY_LOOP.A,MY_LOOP.B,MY_LOOP.C
                );
        END;
    END LOOP;

    FOR MY_LOOP IN MY_CURSOR
        LOOP
            BEGIN
               DELETE FROM TABLE1 Where A = MY_LOOP.ID;
        END;
    END LOOP;
COMMIT;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
ROLLBACK;--if exception occures the rollback happening for the DB1 database only and not happening for DB2
COMMIT;

END;
```

here if exception occurs in the **TABLE1** delete statement then rollback happening for the DB1 database only and not happening for **DB2**

is there any way to do the rollback for the particular **DB2** database

Please help me solve this Thanks in advance

Comment: How about doing the INSERT- and the DELETE-Statement in two different procedures/functions, so you can catch exceptions seperately?

Comment: @Armunin i need to do the whole process in one StoredProcedure at one shot

Comment: Your commit statement should be before the exception.

Comment: @JorgeCampos i have tried that also if exception occurs in the TABLE1 delete statement then rollback happening for the DB1 database only and not happening for DB2 (i.e. the DB2 insert statement is not rollbacking)

Comment: I think that oracle doesn't allow this kind of procedure. A rollback segment is created for a trasaction for one database. I don't know if it will work but you can try to create a savepoint before the insert on db2 and execute your rollback to that specific savepoint. Other approch is to have some sort of info (hash perhaps) on the table from db2 and if you detect a fail you delete those registries with this hash.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. You want to rollback ALL changes to DB1 and DB2 but so far you are only able to rollback the most recent changes?

Comment: @Armunin so far im getting rollback only for the DB1 Changes and not for DB2.

Comment: @Armunin want to rollback ALL changes to DB1 and DB2 but so far only able to rollback DB1 alone

Comment: @JorgeCampos save point also have the same story can be done only for DB1 not for DB2

Comment: Have you tried iterating through the Cursor again and deleting all inserted Rows? Basically implementing your own "rollback"?

Comment: @Armunin if i do that means it will gives the performance issue, i don't wana do my own rollback.. will save point help me in the situation?

Comment: @JorgeCampos thank finally found the solution with your suggestion :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a `savepoint` before the `insert` on **db2** and executed my `rollback` to that specific `savepoint` this solved the issue

Special thanks to @[Jorge Campos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/460557/jorge-campos)

Answer (score 0):

The 'Stop and rollback on error' option does not work when deploying multiple `PL/SQL routines` (stored procedures, user-defined functions, and packages) against an Oracle database server.

Do not deploy multiple `PL/SQL routines` against Oracle using the **'Stop and rollback on error'** error handling option.

If routines that are deployed need to be updated or dropped because of an encountered error,

do so after the deployment process completes by identifying the affected routines in the SQL results view and dropping and re-deploying routines, as required.